# Lattice divisors of 150, ordered by divisibility. Draw Hasse diagram, get complements, check if distributive, check if Boolean.

Tags: divisibility, boolean-algebra, lattice-orders

I have the following exercise:

Having the lattice $D_{150}$ of the divisors of 150, ordered by divisibility
1) Draw Hasse Diagram;
2) Find all complements;
3) Check if it's a distributive lattice;
4) Check if it's a Boolean lattice.

My development:

The divisors are $D_{150} = \left \{1,2,3,5,6,10,15,25,30,50,75,150 \right \}$

point 1)
I have tried to draw the Hasse diagram in this way:
[image: d_150 Hasse]

I have also realized that I can draw two cube structures like the following, and I don't know if this fact can help to resolve the exercise:
[image: d_150 cubes]

point 2)
assuming that I have done right the diagram, I have found some complements, but, not every elements have a complement:

$$\begin{array}{c|c}    
\,       & 1 & 2 & 3 & 5 & 6 & 10 & 15 & 25 & 30 & 50 & 75 & 150 \\     
\hline   1 & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & * \\    
\hline   2 & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & * & - \\    
\hline   3 & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & * & - & - \\    
\hline   5 & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\    
\hline   6 & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & * & - & - & - & - \\    
\hline  10 & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\    
\hline  15 & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\    
\hline  25 & - & - & - & - & * & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\    
\hline  30 & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\    
\hline  50 & - & - & * & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\    
\hline  75 & - & * & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\    
\hline 150 & * & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\    
\end{array}$$

point 3)
I think it is distributive because I can't find any sublattice like the following nondistributive twos:
[image: sublattice_1]
[image: sublattice_2]

point 4)
based on what I have found, since not every element has a complement, then it isn't a Boolean lattice. Or does exists any isomorphism?

please, can you tell what do you think? Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra_(structure)#Examples) that all such lattices are distributive (that is, lattices of divisors of some integer).
Moreover, that they are Boolean iff the number is square-free.
In this case, $25|150$, and $25=5^2$, so $150$ is not square-free and $D_{150}$ is not Boolean.

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complemented_lattice) you see that a complemented distributive lattice is Boolean.
Thus, if $D_{150}$ is distributive and not Boolean, it is not complemented.
Your identification of the complements seems correct.